# Which is better, build a website or use CMS sites?

Tags: content-management-system

I'm attending to build a website that display items like 'laptops...etc'.
The datasource of the items are obtained from XML in URL link...

Can u please advice me which is better, building a website from the scratch, or use CMS system??
If u suggest CMS system, Is there anyway to do it in wordpress or joomla??

the following is a sample of an XML item...

```
<STORE URL="http://www.co.il/" DATE="09/07/2016" TIME="14:29:25" NAME="A.D.S. Soudry Computers ltd" STATUS="ONLINE">
<PRODUCTS>
<PRODUCT>
<PRODUCT_NAME>
<![CDATA[ AGEstar USB 3.0 HDD Docking Station 3UBT6 ]]>
</PRODUCT_NAME>
<CATALOG_NUMBER>28800</CATALOG_NUMBER>
<MODEL>
<![CDATA[ USB 3.0 HDD Docking Station 3UBT6 ]]>
</MODEL>
<DETAILS>
<![CDATA[
*AGESTAR 3UBT6 with two colors black and white for your various choices,is designed with high-grade engineering plastic material.The high-grade engineering plastic is not only solid but also fashionable modeling in unique shape.With using erect and
]]>
</DETAILS>
<PRODUCT_URL>
http://www.co.il/he/product_h.php?idn=28800&arabic=1
</PRODUCT_URL>
<CURRENCY>ILS</CURRENCY>
<PRICE>298</PRICE>
<SHIPMENT_COST>0</SHIPMENT_COST>
<DELIVERY_TIME>7</DELIVERY_TIME>
<MANUFACTURER>
<![CDATA[ AGEstar ]]>
</MANUFACTURER>
<WARRANTY>""</WARRANTY>
<PRODUCT_TYPE>laptops-docking</PRODUCT_TYPE>
<IMAGE>http://www.co.il/images/205_bigagestarusb.jpg</IMAGE>
<TAX>1</TAX>
</PRODUCT>
</PRODUCTS>
</STORE>
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use a CMS if you do not need very specific platform. Specially if you want to display items as in a e-commerce solution.

So, in my opinion:

- Prestashop
- Wordpress with *Woocomerce* plugin
- Joomla with *Ikashop* plugin

Comment: thank u very much for ur reply

i'm programmer that work in .net, i dont know PHP but i can learn
But i dont need to spend a lot of time to figure how joomla or wordpress works to merge the XML datasource with them

so is it easy to do this?? is there a ready options in CMS to read content from XML ??

Comment: In PHP you have native extensions to work with XML. It calls **SimpleXML**: [link](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php). Joomla has built in classes to manage xml as **JFactory/getXMLParser** :  [link](https://docs.joomla.org/JFactory/getXMLParser)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you for any shoping websites use woocommerce plugin on wordpress

Comment: Please Use comment for this type of suggestions.